# Use Flags instead of links for language switching?

Tags: multilingual, impresspages

Is there a way to use flags instead of the language shortcodes for the language switcher links in ImpressPages 4?

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any information on this and am not really clear where that code is generated in the php files...

many thanks
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override default view file that prints language selection. In this case it's `Ip/Internal/Config/view/languages.php`

To do that you need to create a corresponding file in your theme's `override` directory. The path to the file should be like this - `Theme/YOUR_THEME_NAME/Ip/Internal/Config/view/languages.php`

More about view file and how to override them - http://www.impresspages.org/docs/view

Just copy the original view file to a new location and make any changes you like. And you'll be safe with system updates.

Comment: better late than never: Many thanks, works like a charm!